# Short circuit and early return from iterator closure

Tags: rust

I have this newtype which only contains valid states (alphabetic characters) (I'm willing to take suggestions on my naming of this struct. *Alphabetic* maybe?)

```rs
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Hash, Clone, Copy)]
pub struct Character(char);

impl TryFrom<char> for Character {
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn try_from(value: char) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        let value_uppercase = value.to_ascii_uppercase();
        match value_uppercase {
            'A'..='Z' => Ok(Character(value_uppercase)),
            _ => Err("Parsing error: only valid characters are A-Z"),
        }
    }
}
```

There's another type that's implemented as a vec of these newtypes

```rs
pub struct Cipher(Vec<Character>);

impl FromStr for Cipher {
    type Err = &'static str;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        let mut cipher: Cipher = Cipher::new();
        let mut set: HashSet<Character> = HashSet::new();
        s.chars()
            .into_iter()
            .map(|c| Character::try_from(c)) // Result<Character,&'static str>
            .for_each(|c| {
                match c {
                    Ok(value) => {
                        set.insert(value);
                        cipher.0.push(value)
                    }
                    Err(e) => panic!("{:?}", e), // Panics within the closure (sub optimal)
                };
            });

        match (set.len(),s.len()){
                (26,26) => Ok(cipher),
                _ => Err("Parsing error: cipher does not contain enough characters(26) Is a character duplicated in the cipher?")
            }
    }
}
```

The behavior of my `FromStr` implementation leads to failures in a unit test

```
#[test]
    fn only_alphabetics() {
        match Cipher::from_str("1234567890*+-;'!@#$%^&*()_") {
            Ok(_) => {
                panic!("Should not be able to construct cipher with non-alphabetic characters")
            }
            Err(_) => (),
        }
    }
```

Since `from_str` panics within the closure rather than returning an error type, I can't properly write a test case for this function. From my iterator over `s.chars()` i'm doing 2 things, Checking that each char passed is valid and building a `Cipher` or returning an `Err`. If any string contains even a single invalid char, I'd like for this function to return an error instead of panicking.

In short, how do i get from `Vec<Result<Character,&'static str>>` to `Result<Cipher,&'static str>`?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is one of those cases where `for_each` actually hurts you. If you absolutely want to use it, use `try_for_each` instead. But I'd argue that this is a good place for using a normal `for` loop instead:

```rust
use std::{collections::HashSet, convert::TryFrom, str::FromStr};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Hash, Clone, Copy)]
pub struct Character(char);

impl TryFrom<char> for Character {
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn try_from(value: char) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        let value_uppercase = value.to_ascii_uppercase();
        match value_uppercase {
            'A'..='Z' => Ok(Character(value_uppercase)),
            _ => Err("Parsing error: only valid characters are A-Z"),
        }
    }
}

pub struct Cipher(Vec<Character>);

impl FromStr for Cipher {
    type Err = &'static str;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        let mut cipher: Cipher = Cipher(Vec::new());
        let mut set: HashSet<Character> = HashSet::new();
        for c in s.chars().into_iter().map(Character::try_from) {
            let value = c?;
            set.insert(value);
            cipher.0.push(value);
        }

        match (set.len(), s.len()) {
            (26, 26) => Ok(cipher),
            _ => Err("Parsing error: cipher does not contain enough characters(26) Is a character duplicated in the cipher?")
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn only_alphabetics() {
    match Cipher::from_str("1234567890*+-;'!@#$%^&*()_") {
        Ok(_) => {
            panic!("Should not be able to construct cipher with non-alphabetic characters")
        }
        Err(_) => (),
    }
}
```

```
$ cargo test --tests

running 1 test
test only_alphabetics ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s
```

---

Alternatively, you can directly collect `Iter<item = Result<T>>` into a `Result<Vec<T>>`, effectively unwrapping the `Result`. To my knowledge, this does short-circuit.

```rust
impl FromStr for Cipher {
    type Err = &'static str;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        let cipher = Cipher(
            s.chars()
                .into_iter()
                .map(Character::try_from)
                .collect::<Result<_, _>>()?,
        );

        let set: HashSet<Character> = cipher.0.iter().copied().collect();

        match (set.len(), s.len()) {
            (26, 26) => Ok(cipher),
            _ => Err("Parsing error: cipher does not contain enough characters(26) Is a character duplicated in the cipher?")
        }
    }
}
```

---

Note that using `HashSet` for determining duplicates is quite slow.

According to [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/b4cxrj/comment/ej60wir/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), using `sort()` and `dedup()` is much faster. (note that `Character` needs to derive `PartialOrd, Ord`, but I'd argue it should do that either way)

```rust
impl FromStr for Cipher {
    type Err = &'static str;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        let cipher = Cipher(
            s.chars()
                .into_iter()
                .map(Character::try_from)
                .collect::<Result<_, _>>()?,
        );

        let mut unique_chars = cipher.0.clone();
        unique_chars.sort();
        unique_chars.dedup();

        match (unique_chars.len(), s.len()) {
            (26, 26) => Ok(cipher),
            _ => Err("Parsing error: cipher does not contain enough characters(26) Is a character duplicated in the cipher?")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `for_each()` with `try_for_each()`, which is designed exactly for such situations:

```
s.chars()
    .into_iter()
    .map(Character::try_from) // Result<Character,&'static str>
    .try_for_each(|c| {
        let value = c?;
        set.insert(value);
        cipher.0.push(value);
        Ok(())
    })?;
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7d9d0f49fa892240ed19f496436b7f5e)